# How to select an active date within jquery calendar and selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Jquery Calender which shows the working days of the week, and also shows which days are active (i.e. weekend days are not active, and also days which are in the past are not active)

I was wondering if anyone would know where to start using seleiumn webdriver how to select an active day within the jquery calender

Below is the Calender code that I'm trying to write a test for

```
 <DIV CLASS="hasDatepicker" ID="txtDate"><DIV CLASS="ui-datepicker-inline ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"
 STYLE="display: block;"><DIV CLASS="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"><A CLASS="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled"
 TITLE="Prev"><SPAN CLASS="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</SPAN></A><A CLASS="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all" DATA-EVENT="click" DATA-HANDLER="next"
 TITLE="Next"><SPAN CLASS="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Next</SPAN></A><DIV CLASS="ui-datepicker-title"><SPAN CLASS="ui-datepicker-month">June</SPAN>&nbsp;?<fw<SPAN CLASS="ui-datepicker-year">2014</SPAN></DIV>
  </DIV>
  <TABLE CLASS="ui-datepicker-calendar">
     <THEAD>
     <TR>
        <TH CLASS="ui-datepicker-week-end"><SPAN TITLE="Sunday">Su</SPAN></TH>
        <TH><SPAN TITLE="Monday">Mo</SPAN></TH>
        <TH><SPAN TITLE="Tuesday">Tu</SPAN></TH>
        <TH><SPAN TITLE="Wednesday">We</SPAN></TH>
        <TH><SPAN TITLE="Thursday">Th</SPAN></TH>
        <TH><SPAN TITLE="Friday">Fr</SPAN></TH>
        <TH CLASS="ui-datepicker-week-end"><SPAN TITLE="Saturday">Sa</SPAN></TH>
     </TR>
     </THEAD>
     <TBODY>
     <TR>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">1</SPAN></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">2</SPAN></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">3</SPAN></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">4</SPAN></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">5</SPAN></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">6</SPAN></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">7</SPAN></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">8</SPAN></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">9</SPAN></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">10</SPAN></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">11</SPAN></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">12</SPAN></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">13</SPAN></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">14</SPAN></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">15</SPAN></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined ui-datepicker-today"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">16</SPAN></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">17</SPAN></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-days-cell-over undefined"
            DATA-EVENT="click" DATA-HANDLER="selectDay" DATA-MONTH="5"
            DATA-YEAR="2014"><A CLASS="ui-state-default" HREF="#">18</A></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" undefined" DATA-EVENT="click"
            DATA-HANDLER="selectDay" DATA-MONTH="5" DATA-YEAR="2014"><A CLASS="ui-state-default"
                                                                        HREF="#">19</A></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" undefined" DATA-EVENT="click"
            DATA-HANDLER="selectDay" DATA-MONTH="5" DATA-YEAR="2014"><A CLASS="ui-state-default"
                                                                        HREF="#">20</A></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">21</SPAN></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">22</SPAN></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" undefined" DATA-EVENT="click"
            DATA-HANDLER="selectDay" DATA-MONTH="5" DATA-YEAR="2014"><A CLASS="ui-state-default"
                                                                        HREF="#">23</A></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" undefined" DATA-EVENT="click"
            DATA-HANDLER="selectDay" DATA-MONTH="5" DATA-YEAR="2014"><A CLASS="ui-state-default"
                                                                        HREF="#">24</A></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" undefined" DATA-EVENT="click"
            DATA-HANDLER="selectDay" DATA-MONTH="5" DATA-YEAR="2014"><A CLASS="ui-state-default"
                                                                        HREF="#">25</A></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" undefined" DATA-EVENT="click"
            DATA-HANDLER="selectDay" DATA-MONTH="5" DATA-YEAR="2014"><A CLASS="ui-state-default"
                                                                        HREF="#">26</A></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" undefined" DATA-EVENT="click"
            DATA-HANDLER="selectDay" DATA-MONTH="5" DATA-YEAR="2014"><A CLASS="ui-state-default"
                                                                        HREF="#">27</A></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">28</SPAN></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined"><SPAN CLASS="ui-state-default">29</SPAN></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" undefined" DATA-EVENT="click"
            DATA-HANDLER="selectDay" DATA-MONTH="5" DATA-YEAR="2014"><A CLASS="ui-state-default"
                                                                        HREF="#">30</A></TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;?<fw</TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;?<fw</TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;?<fw</TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;?<fw</TD>
        <TD CLASS=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;?<fw</TD>
     </TR>
     </TBODY>
  </TABLE>
```

I've tried and used the following code but feel that this is getting me nowhere, as i have to hard code the date in.

```
        IWebElement dateWidget = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("txtDate"))
        IList<IWebElement> rows = dateWidget.FindElement(By.TagName("tr"));
        IList<IWebElement> columns = dateWidget.FindElement(By.TagName("td"));

        for (IWebElement cell in columns)
        {
            if(cell.Text.Equals("13") && cell.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#txtDate > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(1)")))
            {
                cell.FindElement(By.LinkText("13")).Click();
            }
        }
```

Comment: So what do you intend to do? The test must know what date to use, so it has to come from somewhere? Also BTW, I'd bet that looping through like that is probably not the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: @Arran I intend to select one of the dates that are active so that it triggers the 'Next' button that we have to be active, so that I can select it to go to the next page. I would agree that the for loop may not the best, but this is my first attempt at it, any advice would be gratefully received.

Comment: Write out your steps in English / pseudo code and code that! Come back with specific questions.